# How can I console log this object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maby it just oversee it but I can't console log the value

So when I log this

```
console.log($scope.data)
```

Than I get back in the console on the page

```
$$state: Object
status: 1
    value: Array[11]
    0: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    5: Object
    6: Object
    7: Object
    8: Object
    9: Object
    10: Object
```

I would just say that

```
console.log($scope.data.value[0])
```

Gives me just the first object in the value. 
But I only get undefined with whatever I try to use.
What do I miss that I can't just get my value of the object separately.
Maby it is a angular thing because of the $$ but im kinda clueless right now.

[Here is a screenshot of what I get when I console log the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8io8o.jpg)

**update for posting my code how I get my data:**

Factory

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('testApp')
    .factory('storage', storage);

storage.$inject = ['$http'];

function storage($http) {
    return {
        getData: getData
    };

    function getData() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:4040/')
            .then(complete)
            .catch(failed);

        function complete(response) {
            var merge = data.teams.map (function (data) {
                data.members = response.data.filter (function (person) {
                    return person.room == data.rooms
                });
                return data;
            });
            return merge;
        }

        function failed(error) {
            console.log('getting the data has failed' + error.data);
        }
    }
}
})();
```

service

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('testApp')
    .service('testStorage', testStorage);

testStorage.$inject = ['storage'];

function testStorage(storage) {
    //Create empty variables


    //Data in variables
    var allData = storage.getData();

    //Return functions
    var service = {
        getAll: getAll
    };

    return service;

    ///////////////////////////
    // Create functions here //
    ///////////////////////////

    function getAll() {
        return allData;
    }

}
})();
```

and final my controller

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('testApp')
    .controller('tryOutController', tryOutController);

tryOutController.$inject = ['$scope', 'testStorage'];

function tryOutController($scope, testStorage) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data = testStorage.getAll();

    console.log($scope.data);

}
})();
```

Comment: You could access it like `$scope.data.$$state.value[0]` but this is not what you should do. Post your code for better solutions. How do you populate this `$scope.data`?

Comment: Ye I would say also but I get back 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'. but don't know how I can recreate this problem because it is pretty new for me also never had trouble with it.

Comment: Don't recreate the problem, post your code, how do you populate $scope.data?

Comment: Ehm I will update my post moment

Comment: Edited my main post @dfsq

Comment: So yea, you are trying to use your data before you populate it. Check my answer for how you should set $scope.data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that you are trying to access your data before it's populated. Use proper promises capabilities:

```
function tryOutController($scope, testStorage) {
    $scope.data = {};
    testStorage.getAll().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log($scope.data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ye that was the problem, thanks alot. Is it better to use the promise in the service I create the functions to send back, or just in the controller. update : nevermind, I didnt say anything haha

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're logging the object before it has the values on it. The console, on many browsers (like Chrome), logs a reference to the object which the console uses later if you expand it. This means that when you expand the object in the console later, you see the values as they are *then*, not as they were when you logged the object.

So if `console.log($scope.data.value[0])` is showing you `undefined` but `console.log($scope.data)` shows you a `value` array which, when you expand it, has values it it, that means it got filled in after it was logged.

**But**: Looking at your first example, I think you should be looking at `$scope.data.$$state.value[0]`, not `$scope.data.value[0]`.

Comment: Chrome should have a little blue `i` icon next to the originally logged item to indicate it's doing this.

Comment: That would make sense since I generating the data from a custom node api wth everytime random values. So I should put in my service something like a watcher that waits when there is something injected and than put it out to the controller.

Answer (score -2):

The code below will "stringify" (convert to a string representation) any object that is passed to it. So, in your case you have an array of objects so this will print the first one in that array.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.data.value[0]));
```

You could go further and use a for loop to iterate over the array and print each in turn:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.value.length; i++) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.data.value[0]));
   // For spacing...
   console.log('---------------------');
}
```

Comment: Why is this such a bad answer?

Comment: Putting aside whether it's correct or not, it's just a code dump with no explanation, and unformatted code with syntax errors at that.